# Azure IoT Hub, EventHub and Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

I have an IoTHub with a [route](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-iot-hub-message-routing-enhances-device-telemetry-and-optimizes-iot-infrastructure-resources/) that points to an EventHub which triggers a Functions.

I'm having problem getting the *DeviceId* and other IoT Hub properties from the event object without adding those explicitly to the payload.

If I set the input type to a `string` (or a custom type):

```
public static void Run(string iotMessage, TraceWriter log) {
    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {iotMessage}");
}
```

I only get the payload without any other IoT Hub properties like *DeviceId*, *CorrelationId* or *MessageId*.

I tried to set the type to `EventData` instead:

```
public static void Run(EventData iotMessage, TraceWriter log) {
    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(iotMessage)}");
}
```

Now I can access the IoT Hub properties via two getters: Properties and SystemProperties. For example I can access DeviceId like this `iotMessage.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"]`. But it does not expose the payload.

So how do I access both IoT Hub properties and the payload?

Comment: You should post your answer to the original question (which you mark as UPDATE) as a real answer. It is OK answering his own questions. That way it will be easier to quickly get the answer to the problem. (Thanks anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed a thing in the documentation for EventData. It has a method called GetBytes() and returns the body as a byte array. Example of getting both the IoT Hub properties and the body:

```
public static async void Run(EventData telemetryMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    var deviceId = GetDeviceId(telemetryMessage);
    var payload = GetPayload(telemetryMessage.GetBytes());

    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message.  deviceId: { deviceId }, payload: { JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload) }");
}

private static Payload GetPayload(byte[] body)
{
    var json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(json);
}

private static string GetDeviceId(EventData message)
{
    return message.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the recommended way of doing this, if you need access to detailed event properties in addition to the payload. The simple/default bindings for `string` etc. are useful in cases where you don't need to access those event properties. Our runtime calls `EventData.GetBytes()` for you behind the scenes and converts the data to the input type you've specified.

I do think we could make improvements to facilitate these scenarios however. I've logged a bug [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1004) in our repo to track this.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [upcoming updates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1004#issuecomment-287934705) that will simply this according to this:

> Added first class binding data support for many of the important
>   ServiceBus and EventHub message/event properties. For EventHub:
>
> - PartitionContext
> - PartitionKey
> - Offset
> - SequenceNumber
> - EnqueuedTimeUtc
> - Properties
> - SystemProperties
>
> For ServiceBus:
>
> - DeliveryCount
> - DeadLetterSource
> - ExpiresAtUtc
> - EnqueuedTimeUtc
> - MessageId
> - ContentType
> - ReplyTo
> - SequenceNumber
> - To
> - Label
> - CorrelationId
> - Properties

So you should be able to bind to these properties as well as the payload.