# Get device ID and payload in Azure Function trigered from IoT Hub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

I have Azure Function that is triggered from IoT Hub (Azure Event Hub).

I can only get message that device send but not the device ID. Because of security reasons I do not want to send device ID in message itself. This somehow should be possible based on this post:

[Azure IoT Hub, EventHub and Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003600/azure-iot-hub-eventhub-and-functions)

I tried to change:

```
public static void Run(string myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
```

with

```
public static void Run(EventData myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
```

but I get error:

> The type or namespace name 'EventData' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to find some documentation how to do that but without success. All that I could find was upper post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are just missing the reference and using statement

```
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"

using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
```

Comment: Can I get some help here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240143/eventhubtriggerattribute-does-not-exists-in-namespace-microsoft-azure-webjobs