# EventHubTriggerAttribute does not exists in namespace 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Following steps are taken to create Azure Function in Visual Studio

1. Create New Project and choose `Azure Function` template

[image]

2. Select Azure Function V2 (.net code ) and `IoT Hub Trigger`

[image]

3. Code generated but with reference errors.

   ```
    using IoTHubTrigger = Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubTriggerAttribute;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
    using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    namespace DeviceMessageFunction_v2
    {
      public static class Function1
      {
         private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

         [FunctionName("Function1")]
         public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "")]EventData message, ILogger log)
         {
            log.LogInformation($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array)}");
         }
      }
    }
   ```

> CS0234    The type or namespace name 'EventHubTriggerAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    DeviceMessageFunction_v2    C:\Functions\DeviceMessageFunction_v2\Function1.cs

Tried add references, but no luck

[image]

**Here is my tools and framework details**

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
- Version 15.7.4
- Microsoft .NET Framework
- Version 4.7.02558
- Installed Version: Enterprise
- Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.0.40608.0
- Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   15.9.02046.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using a V2 function you need to use an extra NuGet Package, [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs)

([Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1558))